# Unable to activate specific PHP version

Tags: php, centos, yum

My webserver (Apache on centos7) does not load the installed PHP version.

`php -v` says I'm running `PHP 8.1.16`.
But Apache always loads `PHP 7.2`. But I was running V7.4 until now.

Don't know, but on nightly update routine the following package was updated:

```
php-pear.noarch    1:1.10.13-5.el7.remi    remi-php72
```

However, I am not able to locate ANY installed PHP versions but only this one:
`/etc/httpd/modules/librh-php72-php7.so` which is also referenced by my config file in `conf.modules.d/15-rh-php72-php.conf`.

I have spent nor hours just to locate any PHP installations. But only find the mentioned one.

--

Out of `sudo yum list installed | grep php` command:

```
gd3php.x86_64                         2.3.3-7.el7.remi               @remi-safe 
oniguruma5php.x86_64                  6.9.8-1.el7.remi               @remi-safe 
php.x86_64                            8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-bcmath.x86_64                     8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-cli.x86_64                        8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-common.x86_64                     8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-devel.x86_64                      8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-fedora-autoloader.noarch          1.0.1-2.el7                    @epel      
php-fpm.x86_64                        8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-gd.x86_64                         8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-gmp.x86_64                        8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-intl.x86_64                       8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-kolab-net-ldap3.noarch            1.0.7-2.el7                    @epel      
php-ldap.x86_64                       8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-mbstring.x86_64                   8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                    8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-pdo.x86_64                        8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-pear.noarch                       1:1.10.13-5.el7.remi           @remi-php72
php-pear-Auth-SASL.noarch             1.0.6-5.el7                    @epel      
php-pear-Mail-Mime.noarch             1.10.2-1.el7                   @epel      
php-pear-Net-IDNA2.noarch             0.1.1-10.el7                   @epel      
php-pear-Net-LDAP2.noarch             2.1.0-1.el7                    @epel      
php-pear-Net-SMTP.noarch              1.7.3-1.el7                    @epel      
php-pear-Net-Sieve.noarch             1.3.4-4.el7                    @epel      
php-pear-Net-Socket.noarch            1.0.14-1.el7                   @epel      
php-pecl-imagick-im6.x86_64           3.7.0-1.el7.remi.8.1           @remi-php81
php-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64                1.0.5-1.el7.remi.8.1           @remi-php81
php-pecl-zip.x86_64                   1.21.1-1.el7.remi.8.1          @remi-php81
php-process.x86_64                    8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-pspell.x86_64                     8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-sodium.x86_64                     8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php-xml.x86_64                        8.1.16-1.el7.remi              @remi-php81
php72.x86_64                          2.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php72-php-cli.x86_64                  7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-common.x86_64               7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-fpm.x86_64                  7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-gd.x86_64                   7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-json.x86_64                 7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-mbstring.x86_64             7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-mysqlnd.x86_64              7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-opcache.x86_64              7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-pdo.x86_64                  7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-xml.x86_64                  7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-php-xmlrpc.x86_64               7.2.34-16.el7.remi             @remi-safe 
php72-runtime.x86_64                  2.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php74.x86_64                          1.0-3.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php74-php-cli.x86_64                  7.4.33-4.el7.remi              @remi-safe 
php74-php-common.x86_64               7.4.33-4.el7.remi              @remi-safe 
php74-php-json.x86_64                 7.4.33-4.el7.remi              @remi-safe 
php74-runtime.x86_64                  1.0-3.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
rh-php72.x86_64                       1-2.el7                        @centos-sclo-rh
rh-php72-php.x86_64                   7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-cli.x86_64               7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-common.x86_64            7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-gd.x86_64                7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-intl.x86_64              7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-json.x86_64              7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-mbstring.x86_64          7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-mysqlnd.x86_64           7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-opcache.x86_64           7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-pdo.x86_64               7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-pear.noarch              1:1.10.5-1.el7                 @centos-sclo-rh
rh-php72-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64         5.1.12-1.el7                   @centos-sclo-rh
rh-php72-php-process.x86_64           7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-xml.x86_64               7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-php-zip.x86_64               7.2.24-1.el7                   installed  
rh-php72-runtime.x86_64               1-2.el7                        @centos-sclo-rh
sclo-php72-php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64   2.0.8-1.el7                    @centos-sclo-sclo
sclo-php72-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64    3.4.4-3.el7                    @centos-sclo-sclo
sclo-php72-php-pecl-redis4.x86_64     4.3.0-1.el7                    @centos-sclo-sclo
```

Comment: what does this command return `sudo yum list installed | grep php`

Comment: Can you remove php entirely and try reinstalling php 8 ? `yum remove "php-*" -y`

Comment: Are you sure? what about `yum remove rh-php*` ?

Comment: @Meisterzunge remove all php and try php 8

Comment: You seem to have all 3 php versions installed. if you want to keep all versions, then you can set `AddHandler` in vhost

Comment: Removed anything and reinstalled with no effect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Uninstalled all php versions and installed just `php` - and not any `phpXX` variant.

The `*.conf` file points to `modules/libphp7.so` (wich is the module of the installed `php` package.

Thanks!

Comment: Kind reminder, for a proper "remi" repository configuration and usage, see the Wizard instructions: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/